# Switching from ubuntu gnome to unity

Tags: unity, gnome

I'll preface this by saying I'm still fairly new to most things linux.

I was running ubuntu Gnome for a while and decided I wanted to switch back to unity. So I installed the ubuntu-desktop package through apt-get and everything seemed to work fine.

Now I'm in the Unity desktop environment and everything seems okay except for the bar at the top of any non-maximized app is basically entirely white. It's as if the contrast was turned way up. I can just barely make out the close/minimize button and the title. I really just want to get all of my settings back to how it would be if I had just installed ubuntu unity from the get go instead of gnome first. Is this possible?

Comment: open up `gnome-tweak-tool` & for Theme set Window to  `Ambiance`, GTK+ to `Ambiance`,  Icons to `Ubuntu-mono-dark`. In the Desktop tab set Icons on Desktop to `On`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As doug pointed out in the comments the solution is:

"open up gnome-tweak-tool & for Theme set Window to Ambiance, GTK+ to Ambiance, Icons to Ubuntu-mono-dark. In the Desktop tab set Icons on Desktop to On"